# Call the DLL with Python to get the return parameter

Tags: python, dll

The DLL method is as follows：

```
void _stdcall PostAndRecvEx(IN char* Post, OUT char* Recv)
parameters ：
Post ：input
Recv ：output
Return value: None
```

I wrote the following code in Python：

```
-*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import ctypes,time
lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('API.dll')
keyinfo = '''
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<business id="20002" comment="settings">
<body yylxdm="1">
<keypwd>88888888</keypwd>
</body>
</business>
'''
in_keyinfo = ctypes.c_char_p()
in_keyinfo.value = keyinfo
out = ctypes.create_string_buffer('\000'*32*128)
lib.PostAndRecvEx(in_keyinfo,out)
print out.value
```

But I got the following error：

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "re.py", line 15, in <module>
lib.PostAndRecvEx(in_keyinfo,out)
ValueError: Procedure called with not enough arguments (8 bytes missing) or wrong calling convention
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: In fact, this parameter has been set successfully, but the set result cannot be obtained

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `lib = ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary('API.dll')` to call the DLL with (hopefully) the correct calling convention.

Also, you can just do `out = ctypes.create_string_buffer(32 * 128)` to initialise a null string of that size.

Comment: Thank you. I found the reason for the problem. It started with stdcall, not cdecl